# How i can start internet connection in android emulator(titanium studio) in Mac OS.?

Tags: titanium

i am developing application in titanium studio and OS is Mac. there is no internet connection  available in Android Emulator.i had try using DNS server like in android but in mac i don't know how set DNS server for Emulator. does any body have idea.

please help me..

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Open your `tiapp.xml` file and write down this below line before end of android tag `</android>`

```
<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission</manifest>
```

Now you can access internet in Android simulator

Comment: hi, I have also same problem. but when write this code than, same error is occur. i paste in tiapp.xml this 

<manifest><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission></manifest>